# Azure Function fails and then works

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I've created a Azure Logic App to import credit card transactions into our accounting system by first checking a sftp site for a new file, if there is a file, pulling that file into a sharepoint library, adding a marker to an Azure storage queue with the file name and over-writing the file to be imported in the Azure Storage Account. To complete the import, I then use a custom Azure function that executes a dos command to call a jar file stored in the same Azure storage account which completes the upload.

This has been steadily running for the last two years, saving our accountants quite a bit of time.  However, recently it failed (Feb 9-18). Curiously, after I started poking around it started working again yesterday.

The logic app runs without error message, but the Azure Function was failing. Below is the Invocation details for a failed invocation of the Azure function on 2/18, and a successful run on 2/19. Clearly this is an access issue:

> Exception while executing function: Functions.ULTriggerJava.
> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Access is denied. Access is denied. .

But why? I can see all the files required to execute the function in the Azure storage account. I'm suspecting it is because I use my own work-O365 account to run everything and the stored credential in AzureAD expired.  If you agree that this is the issue, is there any workaround that you might suggest?

Thanks for your help.

Following is the DOS code:

```
echo OFF
rem inputMessage has the path to a file that has the content of the input queue item
rem Read it into an environment variable to make it easier for the Java code to consume
rem As an alternative, the Java code could just read the file itself
SET /p inputMessage=<%inputMessage%
 
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.8.0_73\bin\java" -jar Import.jar --url https://xxx/ --username xxx --password xxx --import credit_card --option paymentMethod=2 --file "CC"
```

Failed Execution:

```
2021-02-16 23:41:51.220
Function started (Id=a8220fc7-47f4-48c0-8f07-4f67a6a8dbf0)
Information
2021-02-16 23:41:51.939
n/a
Information
2021-02-16 23:41:51.939
D:\home\site\wwwroot\ULTriggerJava>echo OFF
Information
2021-02-16 23:42:15.325
Exception while executing function: Functions.ULTriggerJava. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script: Access is denied. Access is denied. .
Error
2021-02-16 23:42:15.342
Function completed (Failure, Id=a8220fc7-47f4-48c0-8f07-4f67a6a8dbf0, Duration=24113ms)
Error
2021-02-16 23:42:15.362
Access is denied. Access is denied.
Error
```

Successful execution:

```
2021-02-19 23:47:37.499
Function started (Id=95b164cd-d58f-4cae-881b-1e6c9ddde47d)
Information
2021-02-19 23:47:38.062
D:\home\site\wwwroot\ULTriggerJava>echo OFF
Information
2021-02-19 23:47:38.062
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.175
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.175
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.194
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.194
This import is running in the command line mode.
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.194
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.194
Purging records imported prior to: 2/20/2020
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.194
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.194
American Express import starting
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.440
53 record(s) purged
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
Total credit card transactions processed: 1
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
Credit card transactions processed: 1
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
American Express import ending
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
Total credit card transactions imported : 1
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
Using Payment Method: CC
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
Total credit card transactions rejected : 0
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
Command line import finished.
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:10.521
Importing credit card transactions from: <b>File</b>
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.258
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.258
This import is running in the command line mode.
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.258
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.258
American Express import starting
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.258
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.258
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.258
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.258
Purging records imported prior to: 2/20/2020
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.409
53 record(s) purged
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
Total credit card transactions processed: 1
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
n/a
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
Using Payment Method: CC
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
American Express import ending
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
Credit card transactions processed: 1
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
Command line import finished.
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
Total credit card transactions imported : 1
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
Total credit card transactions rejected : 0
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.444
Importing credit card transactions from: <b>File</b>
Information
2021-02-19 23:48:20.896
Function completed (Success, Id=96b123dc-d59f-4cad-840c-1e7c9qqqe47g, Duration=43405ms)
Information
```

Comment: Could you further elaborate on what you mean by "stored credential in AzureAD" ? Have you registered a application in Azure AD and use the client id/secret of the registered application ?

Comment: Well, I'm not really sure about what I mean when I say that - I've noticed with Flows and etc that they eventually require that I re-authenticate to keep them running and I wondered if something like that was happening here. However, I did not register an application in Azure AD and do not use a client id/secret for the application. Perhaps my thought about stored credential is a red herring...